# Event Bubbling in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am new in React.js and I am stuck somewhere from 3 days I try many solutions but nothing happens the problem is still there.

I have one parent component called checkout and its child component address there is a two function are bubbling which is `handleSeleteAddress` and `handleDelete` which I mention in the parent. `handleSeleteAddress` is working fine but when I try to delete the object from the array by using `handleDelete` function nothing happen kindly guide me how I can solve this

checkout.jsx(parent):

```js
        class Checkout extends Component {
      state = {
        address: [
          {
            id: 1,
            title: "Home",
            description: "27 Street, 2569 Heritage Road Visalia, CA 93291",
            active: true,
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            title: "Office",
            description: "27 Street, 2569 Heritage Road Visalia, CA 93291",
            active: false,
          },
        ],
      };
    getIndex = (value, arr, prop) => {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if (arr[i][prop] === value) {
            return i;
          }
        }
        return -1; 
      };
    handleSeleteAddress = (index) => {
        var getSeletedIndex = this.getIndex(true, this.state.address, "active");
        const getSelectedObject = [...this.state.address];
        getSelectedObject[getSeletedIndex].active = false;
        getSelectedObject[index].active = true;
        this.setState({ address: getSelectedObject });
      };
    handleDelete = (addressId) => {
        const getSelectedObject = this.state.address.filter(
          (e) => e.id !== addressId
        );
        this.setState({ address: getSelectedObject });
      };
    
    render() {
        return (
          <React.Fragment>
    <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">
                    <AddressSection
                      address={this.state.address}
                      addressClass={this.handleAddressClass}
                      seleteAddress={this.handleSeleteAddress}
                      deleteAddress={this.handleDelete}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 text-center">asd</div>
                </div>
              </div>
    </React.Fragment>
    )
    }
    }
```

AddressSection.jsx(Child):

```
    <div className="addressBoxes">
                {this.props.address.map((div, index) => (
                  <div
                    onClick={() => this.props.seleteAddress(index)}
                    className={this.props.addressClass(index)}
                  >
                    <p>
                      <b>{div.title}</b>
                    </p>
                    <p>{div.description}</p>
                    <div className="edit">
                      <span
                        className="editBtn"
                        onClick={() => this.showEditRodal(index)}
                      >
                        <img src="./assets/images/edit.png" />
                      </span>
                      <span
                        className="deleteBtn"
                        onClick={() => this.props.deleteAddress(div.id)}
                      >
                        <img src="./assets/images/check.gif" />
                      </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
```

Comment: Have you made sure by debuging that the respective functions are not called and right params are getting passed.. ??

Comment: Can you update complete AddressSection code?

Comment: i already check in debuging when i click on div which will call handleSeleteAddress is working fine its receiving index but when i click handleDelete bhot function are calling first handleDelete and then handleSeleteAddress and both are getting parameters.

Comment: Why do you want two different handle click handler?

Comment: Because i have boxes and there is showing address and when i hover on any box there is show small delete button so when i click on box for selecting it will work fine but when i delete any box then having problem it bubbling handleDelete call first and then handleSeleteAddress

Answer (score 0):

You should pass event from AddressSection.jsx(Child) and stop propagation :)

```
 handleDelete = (e, addressId) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        const getSelectedObject = this.state.address.filter(
         (e) => e.id !== addressId
        );
        this.setState({ address: getSelectedObject });
  };
```